# Generating, traversing and printing binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I generated perfectly balanced binary tree and I want to print it. In the output there are only 0s instead of the data I generated. I think it's because of the line in function `printtree` that says `print(tree.elem)`, cause in the class `self.elem = 0`.

How can I connect these two functions `generate` and `printtree`?

```
class BinTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.elem = 0
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def generate(pbt, N):
    if N == 0:
        pbt = None
    else:
        pbt = BinTree()
        x = input()
        pbt.elem = int(x)
        generate(pbt.left, N // 2)
        generate(pbt.right, N - N // 2 - 1)

def printtree(tree, h):
    if tree is not None:
        tree = BinTree()
        printtree(tree.right, h+1)
        for i in range(1, h):
            print(end = "......")
            print(tree.elem)
            printtree(tree.left, h+1)
```

Hope somebody can help me. I am a beginner in coding.

For example:
N=6, pbt=pbt, tree=pbt, h=0

input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and the output:

```
......5 
............6 
1 
............4 
......2 
............3
```

Comment: Can you give one or more examples of input values for a tree & the corresponding expected output to be printed?

Comment: for example N=6 and input would be 1 2 3 4 5 6
i would like to get this output:
......5
............6
1
............4
......2
............3

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind getting that output for that input?

Comment: i see everything is being written in the same line but after printing the tree.elem the next element is in the next line

Comment: i found it on geeksforgeeks that its called printing binary trees in 2-dimensions, the binary tree is printed in vertical

Comment: i actually got a pseudocode from my lecturer that told me to implement it into python but it's a bit hard

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind getting that output for that input?

Comment: You're expecting your `BinTree` nodes to somehow store an integer value, but your `BinTree.__init__()` doesn't take any integer parameter and you just assign `self.elem = 0` regardless, so nodes don't even know their own number. You need to change it to `__init__(self, elem)` and store the integer value, then it could be accessed later by `BinTree__str__()` method that you define on the class, print etc.

Comment: It's hacky that your `printtree` function needs to externally reconstruct/enumerate the sequence of node numbers (`for i in range(1, h):`) rather than just `for node in tree: ...print(node)`. Also you want the `BinTree.__str__()` method to take an optional indent string like your `"......" * depth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest reading up on: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Basically, there are three ways to traverse a binary tree; in-order, post-order and pre-order.

The issue with your print statement is that, you're reassigning the tree that is being passed in, to an empty tree.

```
  if tree is not None:
        tree = BinTree()
```

Right? If tree is not none and has something, lets reassign that to an empty tree.

Traversing a tree is actually a lot more simpler than you'd imagine. I think the complexity comes in just trying to imagine in your head how it all works out, but the truth is that traversing a tree can be done in 3 - 4 lines.

Comment: i see, but i got a pseudocode from my lecturer that he told me to implement and that code is almost the same like the one i posted, so i dont know if i can do it in a different way. And if i delete that tree = BinTree(), i get the erros that says- 'int' object has no attribute 'right'